# Adding pagination in a search result

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I would like to add pagination to the following but not sure how to. In the sense that this query below retrieves a list of items in the database, and the list is quite lengthily where it would be to limit it 10 per page. The problem is that I am not sure how to integrate pagination within the function below.

```
// retrieving items based on the categories
     function getCatCrs(){

        if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
            $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];

        global $con;
        $get_cat_crs = "select * from courses where course_cat1='$cat_id'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY course_date1 ASC";
        $run_cat_crs = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat_crs);

        $count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_crs);
        echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_cats;

        if ($count_cats==0){

            echo "<h2 style='padding:20px;'>No course(s) were found in this category.</h2>";

        }




        while($row_cat_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_crs)){
            $crs_id = $row_cat_crs['course_id'];
                    $crs_cat = $row_cat_crs['course_cat1'];

            $crs_provider = $row_cat_crs['course_provider'];

            $crs_title = $row_cat_crs['course_title'];
                    $crs_price = $row_cat_crs['course_price'];
                    $crs_category= $row_cat_crs['course_cat1'];

                    $crs_image = $row_cat_crs['course_image'];

        $crs_date = $row_cat_crs['course_date1'];
                    $crs_city = $row_cat_crs['course_city'];
    $crs_sdesc= $row_cat_crs['course_sdesc'];
    $crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
            $provider_image = $row_cat_crs['provider_image'];


                    echo "

                                         <article class='search-result row'><center>
          <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
            <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
          </div>
          <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
            <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
            <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
             <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
    <a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
    <a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
            </ul>
          </div></center>
          <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
            <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

            <div id='courseshortDescription'>
    $crs_shortdesc
            </div>  

          <center>  <a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a></center>     


          <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
        </article>


                    ";






        }

    }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: page in 

Notice: Undefined variable: totalRows in 

Notice: Undefined variable: totalRows in 

Notice: Undefined variable: page in 
function getCatCrs(){

    if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
        $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];

    global $con;

    $limit = 10;
$page = (int) isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$offset = ($page) ? ($page - 1) * $limit : 0;
$get_cat_crs = "select * from courses where course_cat1='$cat_id'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY course_date1 ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit";
$sql = "select COUNT(course_title) from courses where course_cat1='$cat_id'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";

$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql));
    $run_cat_crs = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat_crs);

    $count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($run_cat_crs);
    echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_cats;

    if ($count_cats==0){

        echo "<h2 style='padding:20px;'>No course(s) were found in this category.</h2>";

    }

    echo "
<ul id='pagination'>
            <?php if ($page > 1): ?>
            <li class='previous-off'><a href='<?= '$url?page=' . ($page-1) ?>''>Previous</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRows; $i++): ?>
            <?php
            $class = ($page == $i) ? '' class=\'active\'' : '';
            $hl = '$url?page=$i';
            $label = ($page != $i) ? '<a href=\'$hl\''>$i</a>'' : $i;
            ?>
            <li><?= $label ?></li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php if ($page < $totalRows): ?>
            <li class='next'><a href='<?= '$url?page=' . ($page+1) ?>'>Next</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        ";




    while($row_cat_crs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_crs)){
        $crs_id = $row_cat_crs['course_id'];
                $crs_cat = $row_cat_crs['course_cat1'];

        $crs_provider = $row_cat_crs['course_provider'];

        $crs_title = $row_cat_crs['course_title'];
                $crs_price = $row_cat_crs['course_price'];
                $crs_category= $row_cat_crs['course_cat1'];

                $crs_image = $row_cat_crs['course_image'];

    $crs_date = $row_cat_crs['course_date1'];
                $crs_city = $row_cat_crs['course_city'];
$crs_sdesc= $row_cat_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $provider_image = $row_cat_crs['provider_image'];


                echo "

                                     <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
    <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
        </div>  

      <center>  <a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a></center>     


      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>


                ";






    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is use MySQL `LIMIT` range

You could track this by passing a GET param to manage your pagination.

```
$limit = 10;
$page = (int) isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$offset = ($page) ? ($page - 1) * $limit : 0;
$get_cat_crs = "select * from courses where course_cat1='$cat_id'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY course_date1 ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit";
$sql = "select COUNT(somefield) from courses where course_cat1='$cat_id'  AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE()";

$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql););
```

Then you'll need to implement your pagination inside your view

for example...

```
<ul id="pagination">
            <?php if ($page > 1): ?>
            <li class="previous-off"><a href="<?= "$url?page=" . ($page-1) ?>">Previous</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRows; $i++): ?>
            <?php
            $class = ($page == $i) ? " class=\"active\"" : '';
            $hl = "$url?page=$i";
            $label = ($page != $i) ? "<a href=\"$hl\">$i</a>" : $i;
            ?>
            <li><?= $label ?></li>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php if ($page < $totalRows): ?>
            <li class="next"><a href="<?= "$url?page=" . ($page+1) ?>">Next</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. I greatly appreciate. Im just having a little difficulty integrating your suggestion with my previous code.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? The html section is just an example on how it could work. You'll have to modify the echo your doing in your function.

Comment: in the sense that i would like to echo the html part using php the same way i echo my previous code

Comment: Could you paste the full error output? But...You should modify the code for your needs, and not just copy paste. First issue I see is that you have the php tags inside your echo. That will probably not work. I wrote the code for an ex and most likely this use case would occur inside an app that is using MVC.